# Detecting Circular Dependencies In Lerna Monorepo

Tags: javascript, circular-dependency, lerna, monorepo

When publishing packages using `lerna publish`, warnings are output if circular dependencies are detected.

Is there any way to have lerna check for circular dependencies *without* publishing packages?

Comment: Does [*visual*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lerna-dependency-graph) inspection of dependencies work for you?

Answer (score 2):

`lerna bootstrap` will also output the circular dependencies.